# Superclass member pointer becomes null when accessed by subclass

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, subclass

I've been recently doing a lot of reading and decided to try and implement a simple State pattern to try and see how things fit together.

However, I've ran into an issue I've never come across before: The Scene's subclass (Start) doesn't seem to inherit the value of a pointer set by the superclass' constructor.

Here's the code

```cpp
//main.cpp
#include "Game/game.hpp"
#include "Game/Scene/start.hpp"

int main()
{
    Game::Game *g = new Game::Game;
    Game::Scene::Start *s = new Game::Scene::Start(g);
    g->set_scene(s);
    g->loop();
    
    delete g;
    
    return 0;
}
```

```cpp
//Game/Scene/Scene.hpp
#ifndef GAME_SCENE_H
#define GAME_SCENE_H

namespace Game
{
    class Game;
    namespace Scene
    {
        class Scene
        {
        public:
            Scene(Game *game);
            virtual ~Scene();

            virtual void handle_input() = 0;
            virtual void update();
        protected:
            Game *game;
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

```cpp
//Game/Scene/Scene.cpp
#include "scene.hpp"

#include <iostream>

Game::Scene::Scene::Scene(Game *game): game(game) 
{
    std::cout << "Game::Scene::Scene::Scene() > game: " << this->game << std::endl;
}

Game::Scene::Scene::~Scene() {}

void Game::Scene::Scene::update()
{
    std::cout << "Game::Scene::Scene::update(): game: " << game << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
//Game/Scene/start.hpp
#ifndef GAME_SCENE_START_H
#define GAME_SCENE_START_H

#include "scene.hpp"

namespace Game
{
    namespace Scene
    {
        class Start:
            public Scene
        {
        public:
            Start(Game *game);
            
            void handle_input() override;
            void update() override;
        protected:
            Game *game;
        };
    }
}

#endif
```

```cpp
//Game/Scene/start.cpp
#include "start.hpp"
#include "../game.hpp"

#include <iostream>

Game::Scene::Start::Start(Game *game): Scene(game) {
    std::cout << "Game::Scene::Start::Start() > game: " << this->game << std::endl;
}

void Game::Scene::Start::handle_input()
{}

void Game::Scene::Start::update()
{
    Scene::update();
    std::cout << "Game::Scene::Start::update(): game: " << game << std::endl;
    game->set_keep_going(false);
}
```

```cpp
//Game/game.hpp
#ifndef GAME_H
#define GAME_H

#include "Scene/scene.hpp"
namespace Game
{
    class Game
    {
    public:
        Game();
        void loop();

        void set_keep_going(bool state);
        void set_scene(Scene::Scene *scene);
    private:
        bool keep_going;
        Scene::Scene *current_scene;
    };
}

#endif
```

```cpp
//Game/game.cpp
#include "game.hpp"

#include <iostream>

Game::Game::Game(): 
    keep_going(true),
    current_scene(nullptr)
{}

void Game::Game::loop()
{
    while(keep_going && current_scene)
    {
        current_scene->handle_input();
        current_scene->update();
    }
    return;
}

void Game::Game::set_keep_going(bool state)
{
    keep_going = state;
}

void Game::Game::set_scene(Scene::Scene *scene)
{
    if(scene)
    {
        if(current_scene)
        {
            delete current_scene;
        }
        current_scene = scene;
    }
}
```

And here is the output it generates:

```
Game::Scene::Scene::Scene() > game: 00000210FA38B330
Game::Scene::Start::Start() > game: 0000000000000000
Game::Scene::Scene::update(): game: 00000210FA38B330
Game::Scene::Start::update(): game: 0000000000000000
Segmentation fault
```

If I remove the 'this->' part that I used in the subclass constructor for debugging the output becomes this

```
Game::Scene::Scene::Scene() > game: 000001D247B5B370
Game::Scene::Start::Start() > game: 000001D247B5B370
Game::Scene::Scene::update(): game: 000001D247B5B370
Game::Scene::Start::update(): game: 0000000000000000
Segmentation fault
```

Which just makes it even weirder to me that it suddenly decided to reset itself.

It's without a doubt an incredibly simple thing that I'm overlooking, or some pointer shennanigans I've never run into before, but I'm stumped on what can possibly be going on here.

Any help or feedback om my code would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two members variables `Scene::game` and `Start::game`. You never set `Start::game`. By default, `game` resolves to `Scene::game` and the base class's variable is shadowed. Turn on compiler warnings, maybe the compiler will warn about it, not sure in this particular case.

Fix:

```cpp
Game::Scene::Start::Start(Game *game): Scene(game), game(game)
 {
    std::cout << "Game::Scene::Start::Start() > game: " << this->game << std::endl;
}
```

Or just delete `Start::game` and use the member from `Scene`. This probably what you have meant in the first place hence the `protected` qualifier.

If you want feedback - do not use `new`, use `std::unique_ptr` instead. Even better, do not use ptrs at all this is not Java.

Comment: Yup, this was it. Must've forgotten to delete the protected stuff after copying the class. Our of curiosity: with "Don't use pointers" do you mean just the raw pointers? Our just pointers in general?

Comment: @DangerDaisy Current C++ guidelines strongly suggest using smart pointers for ownership and never raw pointers, they (or references) should indicate a non-owning pointer - a pointer that is never responsible for deallocation and has means to detect whether the memory is still alive. That latter can be done based on logical constraints of the program. E.g. you know that `Game` will always outlive scenes, so they can have raw pointers to it. Of course you can use pointers, sorry for not so clear wording.

Comment: That's all right. Not using pointers at all seemed a bit odd. I'm aware that I should probably use smart pointers, but I've always run into issues using them one way or the other so I tend to fall back on the old-fashioned way. Good do some testing up on proper procedure on using them.